# Are typed signatures for stubbed methods not enforced in roles for Perl6?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I am trying to do some OOP with Perl6 and am having a little trouble with roles. I am trying to use them in a similar way to a Java interface, where I would just have method signatures that must be implemented by any class that does the role. I am using stubbed methods with typed parameters and return.

I am noticing that the type signatures are not being enforced though, only the name of the method.

Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

role MyRole {
    method intAdder( Int $a, Int $b --> Int ) { ... }
}

# this does the role and the method signature matches
class MyClass1 does MyRole {
    method intAdder( Int $a, Int $b --> Int ) { return $a+$b }
}

# this does the role and the method signature does NOT match
# why is this allowed?
class MyClass2 does MyRole {
    method intAdder( Str $a --> Str ) { return "Hello, $a." }
}

# this does the role and the method name does not match and gives an error as expected:
# Method 'intAdder' must be implemented by MyClass3 because it is required by roles: MyRole.
#
# class MyClass3 does MyRole {
#     method adder( Int $a, Int $b --> Int ) { return $a+$b }
# }

sub MAIN() {
    my $object1 = MyClass1.new;
    my $object2 = MyClass2.new;
    say $object1.intAdder: 40, 2;
    say $object2.intAdder: 'world';
}

# output:
# 42
# Hello, world.
```

I have read through the Object orientation page in the official docs and can't find a way to do what I want... I am also trying to apply a Java way of thinking about OOP and typing and maybe there is a different, more Perl6ish way to do what I want...

Comment: If this ends up generating a bug report, please consider also referencing https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2146

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you declare a method using `multi method` in the role, then P6 enforces that there's a `multi method` in the consumer with a matching signature. (It allows other signatures too.)

If you omit the `multi` in the role, P6 does *not* enforce the signature, only that a method with the matching name is declared in a consumer.

I don't know why it works this way.

**2020 update** See my commentary beginning "I think the design intent was to support two notions of polymorphic composition" in [my answer to SO "Signature restriction in roles in raku"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163345/1077672). (The 2020 question is a dupe of this one but I didn't remember this one, and unfortunately didn't find it when I searched either.)